# how to use openssl in flask（in" Flask Web Development"）

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, openssl

my code is mainly base on the book <>.
before i use factory functions,i start my application to use https by code like these:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    context=(
        'openssl/server.crt',
        'openssl/server.key'
    )
    app.run('0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=8100,ssl_context=context)
```

and i just input "python hello.py" then it works.

when using factory and blueprint the start code is :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

and i use :"python manage.py runserver" to start my application.but i cloudnt and i dont know how to use openssl to start now.

in addition,does somebody can tell me the difference between openssl and Flask-SSLify?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Flask, but if it's anything like Django, the `manage.py runserver` is only intended for development, where you might not need SSL anyway. In that case, you should run a proper web server (such as ngnix or Apache) in front of Flask. Then deal with SSL in that web server.

Comment: i will have a try and to learn about it ,thank a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest unreleased version of [Flask-Script](https://github.com/smurfix/flask-script), SSL connection is [supported](https://github.com/smurfix/flask-script/blob/master/flask_script/commands.py). To use this, you have to install the package from source code on GitHub instead of **pip**.

After that, apply the following changes to your **manage.py**.

```
server = Server(host="0.0.0.0", port=8100, ssl_crt='openssl/server.crt', ssl_key='openssl/server.key')

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command("runserver", server)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

You can use `python manage.py runserver` to start your app with SSL like you did then.

Comment: He's right. In production environment, we use specific web server to host Flask app instead. Take Nginx for example, you can refer [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) to setup Nginx for Flask, and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority) to install SSL on Nginx.